# unable to create Parquet file in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet

Can any one pls tell me what is the error in the below query.

```
insert overwrite directory 'user/cloudera/batch' stored as parquet select * from emp;
```

I am trying to create parquet table. I am facing the below error when using the above command.

```
cannot recognize input near 'stored' 'as' 'parquet' in select clause
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating parquet table first create table and store as parquet.

```
CREATE TABLE emp (x INT, y STRING) STORED AS PARQUET;
```

now load the data into this table then you can execute your query.

```
insert overwrite directory '/user/cloudera/batch'  select * from emp;
```